# Ember.js: Wrapping JQuery component (Minicolors)

Tags: ember.js

I try to integrate the Minicolor JQuery component in Ember.js application.
Integration should be easy but it does not work for me... (input is displayed but without JQuery component)...

Minicolor integration guide: 
https://github.com/claviska/jquery-miniColors

From doc: simply insert the js file and add the following input:

My js file:

```
App.ColorPicker = Em.TextField.extend({
  type: 'minicolors',
  attributeBindings: ['name'],
   willInsertElement: function() {
    ;
  }
});
```

The html file

```
{{view App.ColorPicker placeholder="Background color" name="color" valueBinding="App.MyController.backgroundColor"}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your issue is that ember is dynamically adding the `<input type='minicolors' ... />` element after the initialization code for minicolors has already executed, causing your new minicolors input to not be initialized.

I got your example working by using the `didInsertElement` event instead of `willInsertElement` event to force minicolors to create the dynamically added `App.ColorPicker` element.  The [willInsertElement](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_willInsertElement) fires when the element is going to be inserted, but hasn't yet, and the [didInsertElement](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement) will fire after the element has been inserted.  I used the latest files from the [minicolors](https://github.com/claviska/jquery-miniColors) github repository.

```
App.ColorPicker = Em.TextField.extend({
  type: 'minicolors',
  attributeBindings: ['name'],
   didInsertElement: function() {
       $.minicolors.init();
  }
});
```

The only other issue I had was needing to make sure the css file and the png with the color picker graphical elements could be loaded.  Apparently if the css and png files are not loadable the js portion doesn't work.

Comment: Tx a lot !!. Works perfectly yet !!